Regex negative lookahead true then ignore rest of regex
I'm using the following IIS Rewrite Rule to block as many bots as possible.
<rule name="BotBlock" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^$|\b(?!.*googlebot.*\b)\w*(?:bot|crawl|spider)\w*" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden" statusDescription="Forbidden" />
</rule>

The goal is to block all user agents with the parts bot, crawl or spider in it, but allow the Google Bot. This works to an extend. But the problem is that the second part of the regex is also triggered, even if "googlebot" is found in the string.
Below some examples what mean:
 Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com)

Works fine, the 'bot' part in googlebot is ignored and the request is permitted.
 Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)

Does not work, still triggers on the second 'bot' in the string and the request is blocked
 KHTML, like Gecko; compatible; bingbot

Works fine, is triggered on the bot in bingbot and the request is blocked
So can someone help me to change the rexeg so the string with Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html) is allowed?

Please make this a complete question by providing a full problem statement, rather than just linking to the previous question.

I'm not familiar with IIS's exact regex flavor (presumably .NET) but this should work if you can enable case-insensitive regex'ing:
^(?!.*googlebot).*(?:bot|crawl|spider)

Explanation:

^ - start line anchor
(?!.*googlebot) - ahead of me, the word "googlebot" does not exist
.*(?:bot|crawl|spider) - capture everything leading up to a positive match of the word "bot", "crawl", or "spider"

The combination of negative look-ahead and positive forward capturing produces an implicit and condition in regex; both must be true in order for the regex to register a match.
https://regex101.com/r/ri6Qs7/1

To note: I am not sure why your regex starts with ^$| unless you are purposely looking to provide a 403 to requests with an empty user agent.

You can omit the second lookahead and match it ^(?!.*googlebot).*(?:bot|crawl|spider)

@Thefourthbird You're absolutely right! It also does seem more performant to boot

^(?!.*google\s?bot).*(?:bot|crawl|spider) would cause "Google bot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com)" to be skipped if that's wanted

Thanks, this works great! And yes, ^$| is to block empty user agents.

Since this question specific to the IIS Url Rewrite Module, I'll focus on that instead of Regex.
You don't have to solve this with a single magical regex pattern.
The rule may consist of multiple conditions involving lighter regex patterns.
<rule name="BotBlock" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <!-- logicalGrouping="MatchAll": all conditions must be met. -->
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <!-- User-Agent must not (negate="true") contain "googlebot" -->
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="googlebot" negate="true" />
        <!-- User-Agent must contain at least one of those words -->
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="bot|crawl|spider" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden" statusDescription="Forbidden" />
</rule>


This also works perfectly. Unfortunately I only can accept one answer. And to block empty user agents use $|bot|crawl|spider

However the advantage of this answer is that you can easily add other agents that you want to allow: googlebot|bingbot

This following pattern will not match if "http://www.google.com/" is behind the "bot", which will allow that specific string to not be matched: ^$|\b(?!.*Googlebot.*\b)\w*(?<!\(\+http:\/\/www\.google\.com\/)(?:bot|crawl|spider)\w*.
